# Code for HTML editor in VB.net wiith asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, fckeditor, html-editor

How to get/attach code for HTML editor in VB.Net with Asp.net 2008, i have to manage static pages of website through HTML Editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regular asp.net see this:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx

TinyMCE is also very popular:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22

And finally you could even use the markdown editor like stackoverflow:
http://wikicontrol.codeplex.com/